# Laravel 5.4 with Entrust: How to get users with roles

Tags: laravel, entrust

I am trying to get all users with roles, but "roles" field is always an empty array.

There are 4 users, 2 of them have at least 1 role attached, verified.

UserController.php

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $users = User::select('name', 'email', 'type')->with('roles')->get();
    return view('user.list', ['users' => $users, 'lang' => Lang::getLocale()]);
}
```

I get the 'roles' field as an empty array, even if I don't use "with->('roles')" in the controller. Weird?

If i print each user role in the view, I get this:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#281 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select also primary key, on which roles are related.
Eloquent is first selecting all users and then based on their IDS (primary and foreign) is selecting relations. If you dont select primary key, he cant relate relations.

```
$users = User::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'type')->with('roles')->get();
```

Also, if you want specifi which columns from roles you want, you have to select foreign key too.

```
$users = User::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'type')->with(['roles' => function ($query) {$query->select('id', 'name', 'user_id');}])->get();
```

Comment: That totally makes sense...and it now works of course! Many thanks