# how to implement entrust in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, entrust

Hi I am new with the use of laravel.I can't understand how to create multiple role user. I want to create an admin and general user . I want to use entrust (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) if possible. I am using Laravel 5.4 and install entrust. If possible an small example with explain of entrust will be helpful.

Comment: Please check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44180000/339367

Comment: it is not clear in it. Whether I should  create new Role in route or in create and declare in a controller. So better a small example file to file with explanation would be much helpful, still thanks @Zubair1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. After creating a project in laravel, open the **composer.json** and update the **require** object with **entrust** like this

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
```

Then Run

```
composer update
```

Step 2. Open **config/app.php** and find **providers** array and add the following line.

```
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
```

Below **providers** array find **aliases** and add the following line

```
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
```

Then Run this command

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

After this you will see a new file in **config** directory named **entrust.php**

Step 3. Open **app/Http/Kernel.php** and add the middleware

```
  <?php
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
    'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
    'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
]; ?>
```

Step 4. Run This

```
php artisan entrust:migration
```

Above command will create the 4 tables **roles**, **permissions**, **role_user** and **permission_role**

Now You are ready to go